# How can you imitate a bagpipe sound with a guitar?

Tags: guitar, instruments, bagpipes

Imitating a violin sound is already known.

[How can I get a violin sound from my electric guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24941/how-can-i-get-a-violin-sound-from-my-electric-guitar)

Also  surprising is how the sound of a Bagpipe ( and other instruments) can be imitated on the Guitar. How does it work?

Comment: Better question: why on earth would anyone want to do this? ;p

Comment: Check out the 1980's band **Big Country**, maybe starting with their song _In a big country_. They were renowned in the 1980's for their "guitars that sounded like bagpipes". And their drummer is the awesome Mark Brzezicki

Comment: You ask as though it's a standard technique. If you want an explanation of how it works, you should explain what process you're talking about. Or is this a question of how to imitate a bagpipe on guitar?

Comment: @ user 45266: *Or is this a question of how to imitate a bagpipe on guitar?* That’s exactly my question. I didn’t ask about a standard technique. The question is following the other question about imitating a violin on the guitar. –

Comment: @user45266, could you explain your vote to close? Is there an edit to the question that would clarify some confusion?

Answer (score 8):

This guy works it with a 5 cent coin:

*All the instruments were reproduced using the clean sound (except for the bagpipes for which I used the distortion).*

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Mind = blown.

Comment: so could you please upvote the question ;)